# Python function input same but doesn't work

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have no idea why this doesn't work.

I am modifying some existing code.  In one of the calls, it the value is hard coded, and I want to us a value that comes in.  For now both are exactly the same and I print them out for testing, but when I pass them into the function, one works and the other does not.

Is this a type thing, I thought Python converted stuff for you automatically or didn't care.

```
class Client( threading.Thread ):
    HOUSIMFILE    = 'C:/projects/HoudiniCom/RamCode/houdini/hip/fu_sim_fullroom_crdpump_hydunit_multiple_wshader_v13b.hipnc'

....
def run(self):
    try:
        print self.__class__.HOUSIMFILE
        print inPacket.actionData.itemName #printed text is the same

        #hou.hipFile.load(self.__class__.HOUSIMFILE, True ) #This call works
        hou.hipFile.load(inPacket.actionData.itemName, True ) #This call fails
    except:
        print "FUSimServer: Can't Start Simulation"
        pass
```

Edit
using repr I get the following

'C:/projects/HoudiniCom/RamCode/houdini/hip/fu_sim_fullroom_crdpump_hydunit_multiple_wshader_v13b.hipnc'

u'C:/projects/HoudiniCom/RamCode/houdini/hip/fu_sim_fullroom_crdpump_hydunit_multiple_wshader_v13b.hipnc'

Why does the second one have a u on the front?

Comment: they are not the same... try `print repr(self.__class__.HOUSIMFILE)` and `print repr(inPacket.actionData.itemName)` and compare

Comment: Your are correct
outputs
'C:/projects/HoudiniCom/RamCode/houdini/hip/fu_sim_fullroom_crdpump_hydunit_multiple_wshader_v13b.hipnc'
u'C:/projects/HoudiniCom/RamCode/houdini/hip/fu_sim_fullroom_crdpump_hydunit_multiple_wshader_v13b.hipnc'

Why does the one have a "u" in front of it

Comment: How about swap the order of that two load line? Maybe because you load file two times which cause problem?

Comment: I only call one of them, I just put both in to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string starting with `u` is unicode.

Comment: OK, got it I just need to wrap it with str load(str(varName))

Comment: That's the idea. Thumbs up!